# Drupal 8 Taxonomy term in twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I want to enhance the title of a page with a taxonomy term value that has been set in a field.

So the title looks like this:

## Title - [taxonomy-term-value]

To modify the title, i overwrote

```
field--node--title--[content-type].html.twig
```

So far so good, access to the node itself and the other fields are requested through the element object:

```
element['#object'].get('field_my_field').get(0)
```

To get the first element.

```
element['#object'].get('field_my_field').get(0)['target_id']
```

returns the tid of the taxonomy term. But

```
element['#object'].get('field_my_field').get(0)['name']
```

returns an empty element.

How can the field value be retrieved? I cannot imagine that this should require php code.

**Update:**
I figured out a way, but it seems a bit complicated:

Since the taxonomy terms are not resolved in #object, i had to add a hook_preprocess:field function to prepare a variable with the necessary data:

```
function myTheme_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook){
  if ($variables['field_name'] == 'title'){
    $variables['my_field'] = Term::load($variables['element']['#object']->get('my_field')->get(0)->getValue()['target_id']);
}
```

The field can now be accessed in twig as follows:

```
{{ my_field.name.getValue()[0]['value'] }}
```

To me this seems to be like a lot of work, so a more straight forward approach is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me in a node template was:

```
{{ node.field_name.entity.name.value }}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8, if you only have the TID of the term, the contrib module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak) should let you get the Term name by doing :

```
{{ drupal_field('name', 'taxonomy_term', tid) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work!

```
{{ my_field.name.value }}
```

EDIT:

The way you access the name of a term (or any field) changes depending on the template your code is in.

If you are in a paragraph template you would use:

```
{{ paragraph.field_my_taxonomy.name.value }}
```

If you are in the node template:

```
{{ node.field_my_taxonomy.name.value }}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, looks like you need to set up a proper page_suffix  for the **page-title.html.twig** template, populated by your custom module

Comment: how is this different to the solution i proposed in the updated section other than the code moves from the preprocess to the page_suffix?

Comment: Your solution would work, while mine is a bit closer to the Drupal theming design.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with paragraphs you need to set this up slightly differently to the examples above:

```
{{ content.YOUR_PARAGRAPH_REF['#items'].0.entity.YOUR_TAX_FIELD.0.value}}
```

spent hours looking for this...